# Terraform: Use variable list type for aws Cloudfront resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm having trouble using a list type variable in an AWS Cloudfront resource for the 'alias' argument.

**variables.tf**

```
variable "my_domains" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["one.domain.tld", "two.domain.tld"]
}
```

**distribution.tf**

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "my_domain_com" {
  ...
  aliases = [var.my_domains]
  ...
}
```

This presents an error:

> var.my_domains is list of string with 2 elements.
> Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `aliases` and `my_domains` is already a list:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "my_domain_com" {
  ...
  aliases = var.my_domains
  ...
}
```

Comment: The 'alias' was a typo. I do have it as 'aliases.' Removing the brackets presents the same error, though.

Comment: @MikeD Its not possible to produce the same error. `aliases = var.my_domains` is correct. This means that your question is not representative of your actual code, just like probably your "typo".

Comment: The "aliases" was really a typo as I was not copy/pasting the code, but rather trying to provide an example of what I'm doing in the SO editor. However, your suggestion did work and I was seeing another error related to the "comment" argument and confusing it with the original error. I thank you for your answer.